# only root queries support aggregate expressions

Tags: apex, trigger

I was working on one trigger and using sum in query but I am getting the following error when I tried to save record.

only root queries support aggregate expressions

Can anyone helps me out in this issue here if possible.

```
for (Project__c objProject: [SELECT Name, 
                                (SELECT Project__r.Id, Project__r.Name, sum(Billable_Cost__c) Billablecose, sum(Billable_Dollars__c) billabledollars, sum(Non_Billable_Costs__c) nonbillablecosts, sum(Non_Billable_Dollars__c) nonbillabledollars  from Time__r group by Project__r.Name, Project__r.Id) 
                                 FROM Project__c
                                 WHERE Id in:set_Time ]){
                                         BillableDollars+= double.valueOf(objProject[0].get('billabledollars'));
                                         BillableCost+= double.valueOf(objProject[0].get('Billablecose'));
                                         NonBillableDollars+= double.valueOf(objProject[0].get('nonbillabledollars'));
                                         NonBillableCost+= double.valueOf(objProject[0].get('nonbillablecosts'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to flip the query round and ensure you group the results by project. I expect it to be something like (I have had to guess at your object type API name for "time" and the lookup field for Project:

```
SELECT SUM(Billable_Cost__c) billablecost,
        SUM(Billable_Dollars__c) billabledollars,
        SUM(Non_Billable_Costs__c) nonbillablecosts,
        SUM(Non_Billable_Dollars__c) nonbillabledollars,
        Project__c
    FROM Time__c
    WHERE Project__c IN :set_Time GROUP BY Project__c
```

Of course, this doesn't give you the Project__c instance names, so you would need a separate query for that.

Someone may know of a way to do this in a single query, but I'm not aware of it. NB: If you are running this in a trigger against Project__c then you will already have the Project__c instance names (so no need for a second query).

Comment: I tried your code but still its giving me the same error, yes this code lies in trigger only

Comment: I don't understand why since I can do similar queries successfully using my own custom objects. Perhaps you have some other code not shown in your question that it causing the issue?

Comment: Thanks a lot Phil, I did made some small changes to the query that you provided and am able to solve the issue for now. Thanks for helping me out here